# how to get reference method for class in intellij plugin

Tags: java, intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

I want to develop an IntelliJ plugin 
I have two classes

```
public class A { public void sum() {}}
public class B extends a{ }
```

my question is how to search the references(usages) of **sum** method in class B  without including the usages in class A

I am using ReferencesSearch#search but it gets the method usages in class A

Answer (score 1):

If you need to search for usages only in a single class, you can pass a scope containing that class (`new LocalSearchScope(psiClass)`) to `ReferencesSearch.search()`.

If you need to search for all usages except for those in the class A, you can check whether the usages returned from `ReferencesSearch.search()` are contained inside `A`, using `PsiTreeUtil.isAncestor()`.